# How to launch an Android Activity when multiple pages of the App have Same Activity name in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

I have a screen consisting list of Results. Clicking on each of the result takes me to different item but with the same Activity Name(TestResultActivityDetails).
How can I launch each Result as different Activity Launcher?
Is there any option to use index on list items to launch Activity?

```
val intent = Intent(TestResultActivityDetails::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Here, TestResultActivityDetails::class.java is the activity name which is shared with all the list of Results.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want the TestResultActivityDetails to know the index of the item from which it was started?

Comment: I want to know how to pass the Index to TestResultActivityDetails to launch the Activity, since there are multiple Screens/Pages with the same Activity Name.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to an Activity you need to use Intent extras. Your posted code would become as this:

```
val intent = Intent(TestResultActivityDetails::class.java).apply {
    /* You pass data as extras, with a key and the actual value.
     *         KEY            VALUE */
    putExtras("clickedIndex", index)
}

startActivity(intent)
```

Then, in TestResultActivityDetails you would do:

```
override fun onCreate(saveInstance: Bundle?) {
    ...

    /* You get your data back from the Intent extras, using previous key.
     *                                 KEY               FALLBACK if not found */
    val index = intent.extras?.getInt("clickedIndex") ?: -1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I will try this out and update!